# Not able to run my react native project without errors

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run my react native project via this command: npx react-native run-android

My project was correctly build:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 14s
160 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 159 up-to-date
Running C:\Users\souissi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 5200e76ec04545af reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

But I am getting this error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In C:\Users\souissi\StudioProjects\HHHH\node_modules\babel-preset-react-native-stage-0\index.js
    at createDescriptor (C:\Users\souissi\StudioProjects\HHHH\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:178:11)
    at C:\Users\souissi\StudioProjects\HHHH\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (C:\Users\souissi\StudioProjects\HHHH\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (C:\Users\souissi\StudioProjects\HHHH\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at presets (C:\Users\souissi\StudioProjects\HHHH\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:47:19)    at mergeChainOpts (C:\Users\souissi\StudioProjects\HHHH\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:320:26)
    at C:\Users\souissi\StudioProjects\HHHH\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:283:7
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1)::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2020:08:53:00 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.11.0"
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

[image]

error in config-descriptors.js

```
if (filepath !== null && typeof value === "object" && value) {
    throw new Error(`Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In ${filepath}`);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You can use only ```React``` components as ```<Component/>``` in another component,  It seems to me, you are exporting an object instead of a react component class or function.

Comment: Please share code for the file in which this error is occuring

Comment: error in config-descriptors.js
code added in description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved problem.
I was forced to install an old version of react native
npm install react-native@0.49

this fixed my problem
Thanks for your help

Comment: You should maybe look on what else can cause all of this because react 0.61 is out and using 0.49 is much older^^ if it works for now thats good but keep on looking what can get your app running in a newer RN version - just a tipp ;)